# Differences between the two phrases

Tags: grammar, construction

When and how should I use the phrases “suddenly realized” and “suddenly realize” ?

What are the differences between them? 
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You are really asking about two different verb forms.

*Realized* is the past tense : He suddenly realized he had left his keys at home.

*Realize* is the infinitive : It is alarming to suddenly realize that you don't have your keys with you.